# How fix control Query Persistence QL(hql)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have issue with Hibernate query, my IDEA inspection error syntax:

> This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are
>   error-checked

[image]

But I create mapping for `Task` objects in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/todo_list</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>

    <mapping resource="ru/pravvich/model/Task.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

Facets:

[image]

If I cheating IDE and instead `createQuery("select t from Task t")`, create variable and push in `createQuery`

`String hql = format("select t from Task t where t.id > %s", 0);
 session.createQuery(hql)`

It's work, but it's not normal code. How to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what for me resolve the same issue:
Open in the IDEA Preferences `(Settings)/Editor/Language Injections` and under the list of languages find Session `(org.hibernate)`.
Under the column Language, it should be selected `Hibernate QL`.
Double click on it and a list of operations will be displayed.
Select the operations that you need.
[image: IDEA Settings]

Answer (score 1):

IDEA doesn't recognise which or what Descriptor you are using. Check Project Structure -> Facets -> Hibernate. You should have found a cfg.xml file in Descriptors. If you are using package scanning through spring session factory definition,you should have found a session factory bean. If neither of them exists,you may add one.

Comment: Yes, but on my screen of facets page descriptor `cfg.xml` is selected. Or You mean something else? (No I does not use Spring)